# How can i use group by and order by condition together

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT n.*, u.* 
  FROM notice AS n 
  LEFT JOIN user AS u 
    ON n.userid = u.user_id 
 WHERE  n.interitor = '13' 
   AND n.userid != '13' 
   AND n.deleted = '0'  
  GROUP BY object_id
 ORDER BY createdate  DESC
```

How can i use group by and order by condition together

Comment: `GROUP BY` just needs to come before `ORDER BY`

Comment: usually when you use GROUP BY you will use aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You have no aggregations to group by. But if you did it would look something like this.

```
SELECT
    SUM(n.column) AS sumcolumn,
    u.column1,
    u.column2
FROM
    notice AS n 
LEFT JOIN
    user AS u 
        ON n.userid = u.user_id 
WHERE
    n.interitor = '13' 
    and n.userid != '13' 
    and n.deleted = '0'  
GROUP BY
    u.column1,
    u.column2
ORDER BY
    u.column1,
    u.column2;
```

Comment: You wouldn't normally parse integers as strings

Comment: All I did was update the select, group by, and order by clauses.